# How can I blur the background of table with out blur the row content?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a table on the backgroundview like this:

[image: Table with clear color]

i want to set my tableview with blur animation on the background like this:

[image]

I tried to set the background color of table to black and set the alpha of that to 0.1 :

```
self.lapTable.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.lapTable.alpha = 0.1
```

but when I do that, all of my row have alpha 0.1 too:

[image]

How can I blur the background of table with out blur the row content?

Comment: Instead of setting background color to UITable, Create a custom table cell and add uiview with black color with 0.1 alpha over that view add your label. Hope It will work.

Comment: Sometime, my tableview don't have any row. Show i want to set the tableview background to blur. Thanks

Comment: take a uiview behind the table view with same size and make the uiview alpha 0.5. this will not effect the table and it will blur the background image of table view exactly like you want.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i'm trying to do that, i will show my result!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Successfully to make what i want. simple add another view under my table view and view's background color to black with alpha, after that set the background of tableview to clear color.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set tableview background color clear

```
self.lapTable.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

and make a UIView in background of UITableView and set transparent background of UIView

It will work same as like you ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i want a black blur to show the table , if i set the clear color, i will same result as pic 1.

Comment: Make a other UIView behind Tableview and Set color of that .. 
By using this , it will not effect on your tableview and also change your background color

Comment: Yeah.. i'm digging  this way. :) i will show the result later, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set the background color like in your initial attempt, you could create a translucent color:

```
let translucentBlack = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.6)
```

You could also set `tableView.backgroundView` to an instance of [`UIVisualEffectView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/) with `effect` set to an instance of `UIBlurEffect`.